# Titanium Mobile SQLite Select performance

Tags: sqlite, titanium

I m using latest sdk and studio. developing for ios 7. and I m taking photo with iphone and store the path in sqlite. and I have one tableview showing all photos .each image 1.5 mb and maybe ı want to show 1000 or more photo in same table.

How can speed up this select method?

Comment: Are you really showing 1000 1.5 MB photos on the screen at the same time?

Comment: not really. in a screen 2-3 image when its scrolling it will be loaded

Comment: Is the sql select slow or is it the creation of the tableview and the tablerowviews?